# Rank $r$ matrix $U$ such that $AU=UB$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Is the following equivalence true?

> Let $A, B$ two $n \times n$ matrices with real entries and $1\leq r \leq n$. The following are equivalent:
>
> 1. $A, B$ share $r$ eigenvectors (counting multiplicity).
> 2. There exists a matrix $U$ (of size $n \times n$), of rank $r$ such that $AU=UB$.

In the case $r=1$, then for example one can take two eigenvectors ($x$ for $A$, $y$ for $B$), and let $U=xy^T$. It might be possible to prove the above equivalence by induction.

Answer (score 1):

The implication 2) => 1) is not always true.

Let $A=\text{diag}(1,1,0,0)$, $B=\text{diag}(2,3,0,0)$ and $U=\text{diag}(0,0,1,1)$

It is clear that rank(U)=2 and AU=UB=0

But A and B do not share 2 distincts eigenvalues.

Comment: well, I edited, thank you, know the statement includes multiplicity counting